# Sending notifications from one emulator to another

Tags: android, notifications, sms

I am workng on android emulator , now i am trying to make an application to locate friends .
Here I have to send notifications from one emulator to another , like we send SMS form one to another . Is it possible to do that .

I have tried but notifications was sent only in that same emulator , it was not going to other emulator . if you know tell me about any souce code or tutorial .

Sudhanshu

Answer (score 1):

This would likely require that all devices connect to a central notification server.  The server would then route the notifications to the appropriate users.